# How to combine mutliple calls to a function?

Tags: r

I would like to generalize my function calls to be able to pass these calls to a second function as parameters.

In my case I have mutliple ggplots that I store as a list for example:

```
year.plots <- lapply(c("2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"),
   FUN=function(x){
   ggplot(data=french.temp.load[french.temp.load$Year==x,],
   aes(x=Temperature_K,y=load,color=Month)) +
   geom_point(alpha=0.5)
   })
```

Now I would like to passe them to grid.arrange. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
grid.arrange(seq(year.plots),ncol=3)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. It's hard to be sure since I don't use grid stuff often and you didn't provide a reproducible example.

```
# Make example data
p <- qplot(rnorm(30))
year.plots <- list(p, p, p, p, p, p, p)
# This will basically construct the call
# grid.arrange(p, p, p, p, p, p, p, ncol = 3)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots, ncol = 3))
```

Comment: That was my thought as well. @SamyGeronymos: you use `do.call` when you want to pass a list to a function that takes `...`.