# calling grid.arrange on a list of ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, do.call

This question is linked to this one here:

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341871/how-to-combine-mutliple-calls-to-a-function)

My present question is: In my code I generate a list of ggplots in a list by calling lapply. I use lapply in the first place because I execute a fairly big amount of similar ggplots and it would be too cumbersome to generate each ggplots manually. how can I generalize my code?

```
p <- qplot(rnorm(30))

plist <- lapply(c(1:10),FUN=function(x){

  qplot(rnorm(30))

})

#works
year.plots <- list(p,p)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots))

#works
plist[[1]]

#works
grid.arrange(p,plist[[1]])

#does not work
year.plots <- list(p,plist[[1]])
do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots))

#How to generalize with the following idea?
year.plots <- list(p,plist[[1]],plist[[2]],...)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots))
```

Comment: Using `do.call(grid.arrange, year.plots)` instead of `do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots))` worked for me.

Comment: What do you mean that `year.plots <- list(p,plist[[1]]); do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots))` does not work? It works for me (though the `c()` is unnecessary)

Comment: If you want to combine `p` with the list, do `do.call(grid.arrange, c(list(p), year.plots))`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I see that you discovered it at the same time that I posted my answer. In my opinion it's still usefull, but it's up to you to leave the question.

Answer (score 10):

With gridExtra v>=2.0.0, you can now do,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = year.plots)
```

Comment: nice to know there is a new version, going to update it immediately :-)

Comment: please do, and help me answer the related pile of "my code's now broken" questions here ;)

Answer (score 6):

It's not necessary to wrap the list in `c()`, both `do.call(grid.arrange, year.plots)` and `do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots))` work.

However, if you want to include extra arguments, you will need to wrap them together with the list in the `c()` part like this:

```
do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots, ncol=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm silly I found the mistake in my code after 40 minutes.

```
do.call(grid.arrange, c(year.plots,plist,nrow=3))
```

Comment: Does this really differs from the answer already posted by @Jaap?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the above answer concentrates on the question to know whether a c() should be included or not. I'm answering my own question to know how to plot both "p" s and plist.

Comment: @SamyGeronymos As my answer includes `year.plots` (which contains `p` and `plist`), I guess it is answering your question. Including both `year.plots` and `plist` as in your answer, will lead to doubles IMHO.