# How to create a list of ggplot objects that grid.arrange will accept and draw in r

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, gridextra, grob

**Update** The below code runs now after kernel restart. I'm leaving the question since I didn't see this exact method of converting the plot object into a list and appending.

I want to dynamically create a list of ggplot2::ggplot objects (gg) and pass that list to gridExtra::grid.arrange() to draw them.

However, I'm getting errors when I try (see bottom of code below).

How do I create a list of ggplots and use it in grid.arrange() (or anywhere I want one or more gg objects or grobs)?

I've looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341871/how-to-combine-mutliple-calls-to-a-function) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518246/calling-grid-arrange-on-a-list-of-ggplots), but the solutions didn't work.

Here's a simple example with outputs:

```
# RStudio Version 1.3.1093
# R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
# ggplot2 version 3.3.2
# gridExtra version 2.3

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

test_fun = function (x) {
  plt_lst = list()
  
  for(col in colnames(x)){
    plt = ggplot(data = x, aes(x = x[ , col])) +
      geom_histogram()
    plt_lst = append(plt_lst, list(plt))
    grid.arrange(plt) # Draws each graph.
    print(is(plt))
    # [1] "gg"
    print(is(plt[[1]]))
    # [1] "data.frame" "list"       "oldClass"   "vector"
  }
  
  return(plt_lst)
}

df = data.frame(a = rnorm(n = 50),
                b = rnorm(n = 50))

test_plt_lst = test_fun(df)
print(is(test_plt_lst))
# [1] "gg"
print(is(test_plt_lst[[1]]))
# [1] "data.frame" "list"       "oldClass"   "vector"

# grid.arrange(test_plt_lst)
# # Error in gList(list(data = list(a = c(1.14459276559037, 2.33485713757935, : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"


# Works
do.call(grid.arrange, test_plt_lst)
# The following error no longer appearing.
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "wrapvp", value = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, : replacement has 17 rows, data has 50
```

Comment: use `plt_lst = append(plt_lst, list(plt))`, or even better ditch the for/append loop and use `lappy` because you are still going to have a problem with `aes()` lazy evaluation in this case.

Comment: @MrFlick, haha, thanks. I noticed that as soon as I posted. The problem remains, though the object type is at least intact.

Comment: Well, then you are probably getting a different error message then. You should update that. Because `do.call(grid.arrange, test_plt_lst)` works fine for me after that change. (though it does just print the same plot twice because of the other thing I mentioned)

Comment: Yeah, it works now after restarting the kernel. Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm using a for loop because I'm actually looping through levels in a factored variable and plotting based on the subset (e.g. `for(level_str in level_str_vect){fun(data=df[ , level_str], ...)}`). I've been trying to figure out how to make it work out of principle, but I'm compromising with a for loop since I'm only doing four levels. Maybe I'm stuck thinking in terms of a Python list comprehension and missing how to use lapply here.

Comment: One of the problems is that the function I'd apply has its own x parameter that I need to pass an argument to, which would get mixed up with the x parameter in `lapply`.

Comment: There's nothing about `lapply` that requires a variable to be named `x`. It would just look more like `test_plt_lst <- lapply(level_str_vect, function(level_str) { ggplot(..., data=df[,level_str])})` or something like that. `lapply` returns a list so each function call just has to return an object that you want to add to that list.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks, so if I define the applied function elsewhere, this is proper syntax? `plts = lapply(X = level_vect, FUN = basic_scatter(data = data[ , level_str], x = x, y = y, x_lbl = x_lbl, y_lbl = y_lbl, x_breaks = x_breaks, y_breaks = y_breaks, x_limits = x_limits, y_limits = y_limits, color = color, leg_lbl = leg_lbl, fr = fr, jit_w = jit_w, jit_h = jit_h))` How does `lapply()` know where to plug the vector item?

Comment: You need to supply a function to `FUN=`, right now you are calling a function and passing it's value. The value is passed as the first parameter to that function. It should look like `plts = lapply(X = level_vect, FUN = function(level_str) {basic_scatter(data = data[ , level_str], x = x, y = y, ...)})`

Comment: @MrFlick, aha! There it is! Thanks. Obvious once you point it out. I think I need to step away from the screen for the night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to :

1. Initialise the length of the list because growing objects in a loop is considerably slow.
2. Use `.data` pronoun to subset the names so you get proper names on x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

test_fun = function (x) {
  plt_lst = vector('list', length(x))
  nm <- names(x)

  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    plt_lst[[i]] = ggplot(data = x, aes(x = .data[[nm[i]]])) + geom_histogram()
  }
  
  return(plt_lst)
}


test_plt_lst = test_fun(df)
do.call(grid.arrange, test_plt_lst)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Ronak Shah! It should be noted that using `append` did work when passing the appended `gg` object as the sole object of a list (per appropriate `append` use).